# Set object name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysqljs

In [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), the return value from a connection query is printed as

`[ RowDataPacket { column: "value" } ]`

which is equivalent to `[ { column: "value" } ]`.

How does the library give the `{ column: "value" }` object a "name" `RowDataPacket`?

I thought it might be to do with classes but the below doesn't work

```
class RowDataPacket {
   constructor() {
      self.column = "value";
   }
}

console.log(new RowDataPacket())
```

Comment: That's correct `RowDataPacket` is a class and in get array of `RowDataPacket` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `class` solution **does** work, in Chrome's devtools, at any rate; not, it appears, in Firefox's devtools. (Note that where you've used `self` in `constructor` you wanted `this`, but it doesn't affect the result in devtools other than that the property isn't there.)

```js
class RowDataPacket {
   constructor() {
      this.column = "value";
   }
}

console.log("one", new RowDataPacket());
console.log("array of one", [new RowDataPacket()]);
```

```html
(Look in the real console.)
```

You can take it further if you like, and also apply it to individual objects, by setting the [`@@toStringTag`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-well-known-symbols) of the object (for instance, the prototype of the class), which is used by [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) when building the `[object XYZ]` string for the object, and is also used by some devtools to identify the "type" of the object:

```js
const myObject = {};
myObject[Symbol.toStringTag] = "myObject";

console.log(myObject);
console.log("Default toString", String(myObject));
```

```html
(Look in the real console.)
```

Example using it on a class prototype:

```js
class RowDataPacket {
}
RowDataPacket.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = RowDataPacket.name;
console.log("one", new RowDataPacket());
console.log("Default toString", String(new RowDataPacket()));
```

```html
Look in the real console.
```

Comment: I made a typo, should be `this.column` instead of `self.column` (didn't throw error since `self` is valid keyword). Too much python...